# separating commit messages between modules of a monorepo

Tags: git, lerna

I have a fullstack project like this:

```
myProject
    packages
        myProjectCommon
        myProjectFrontEndApp1
        myProjectFrontEndApp2
        myProjectBackEnd
```

I use Lerna so that I can use `myProjectCommon` as an internal dependency.

If I decide to do a monorepo, I would do something like this:

```
myProject
.git
    packages
        myProjectCommon
        myProjectFrontEndApp1
        myProjectFrontEndApp2
        myProjectBackEnd
```

A major problem that I see with this, is that I will be mixing the commit history of all my packages together.

Is this configuration, is there a tool that would allow me to look at the commit history for a particular package ?

Or is the best solution to do separate repos for each package, and use them as git submodules like this :

```
myProject
.git
.gitmodules
    packages
        myProjectCommon
            .git
        myProjectFrontEndApp1
            .git
        myProjectFrontEndApp2
            .git
        myProjectBackEnd
            .git
```

Answer (score 3):

`git log <glob>` will work. For example: `git log packages/myProjectBackEnd` will show only the commits changing files in that module